# Rewrite markup of a field in twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I want to calculate dynamical a value and give it back in the markup without saving the newValue. I try this with:

```
 {% set content.field_my_field[0]['#markup'] = newValue %}
```

This doesn`t work!
The "newValue" is given from preprocess_node in the .theme file.
Should I rewrite this directly in the preprocess function? How?

Found a solution in preprocess_node. I tried to manipulate $variables['node'] instead of $variables['content']

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['content']['field_my_field'][0]['#markup'] = $newValue;
}
```

Comment: You should just get the raw value from the field, not from the render array.

Comment: I want only override the rendered value and calculate the $newValue form the raw value.

Comment: You can just grab the field value and create a new variable to output in the template. Messing with render arrays isn’t advised. You could also create a field formatter plugin I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't be more verbose earlier, I was typing from a phone.

One way to solve this would be to just create a new template variable. Also, its easier to use the field value instead of parsing the render array - the contents of that array could change without warning. Not saying it happens a lot, but is possible. Just access the field value directly in one of two ways:

`$field_value = $node->get('field_name')->value;`

or

`$field_value = $node->get('field_name')->getValue();`

Note that not all fields will work that way, but most basic ones like text or textlong do. Reference fields for example will work a little differently.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  if ($node->getType() == 'mytype') {
    if (!$node->get('field_my_field')->isEmpty()) {
      $variables['new_variable'] = $node->get('field_my_field')->value;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your `node--node-type.html.twig` template of your theme, where you want the field output, do:

`{{ new_variable }}`

Note that if you use `->getValue()` above, you need to dig into that value array to get the actual value as opposed to `->value`.

Always isolate the effort to the node type(s) and templates it should affect. In your question, you say you have this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['content']['field_my_field'][0]['#markup'] = $newValue;
}
```

This code will fire for every node in the system any time it is loaded on that active theme. Unless that field exists on every single node type, it will cause a lot of warnings/notices in your logs. If you moved the field from visible to hidden from the admin UI, this code will fail as well, since the field will be removed from the `content` render array and not exist. I tend to also enforce checking both the node type *and* the view mode of that node being rendered too, but that is all up to what your design requirements are.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I use if($variables['node']->bundle() == 'mytype') { ... code ... } in the preprocess function. My Code is only a small snipped. When i use it in this way with an extra {{ new_variable }}, than it isn't in the render array and that makes it harder to control the layout in the template for different outputs(views, pdfprint ...). My question was: is it possible to override the markup of the field in the twig template, so that all the other things like weight, field label ... are still the same for this field. Sorry, when my asking is a little bit unclear.

Comment: The only way you are going to get the exact output you want like that is to write a field formatter plugin for it. I wouldn't try manipulating/evaluating things in `#markup` like that, I would just make it do what I wanted it to be in the first place. Using the field formatter will let you keep the field ordering, label etc while staying inside of the render array. See the docs page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter